# Use Rowspan if values are same

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a table in mySQL which stores center name and activities there. I want to display activities in a table center wise. I am using below query to fetch data:

```
$query2 = "SELECT * FROM centres_info_act a, cenert_name b Where a.cnt_id = b.ctn_id";
```

These 2 tables are connected by common column  cnt_id  and ctn_id. The master table is cenert_name in which center name and center address are stored.

Now, when i display it in HTML table then each record is printed in different rows having same center name . For e.g.

```
Example Center         Activity 1         Delete
Example Center         Activity 2         Delete
Example Center         Activity 3         Delete
```

But i want output like below:

```
                       Activity 1         Delete
Example Center         Activity 2         Delete
                       Activity 3         Delete
```

Comment: What language and code are you using to generate the table? What have you tried so far?

Comment: i m using PHP... i tried as `while ( $row2 = @mysql_fetch_array($result2) ) { ?> <td valign="top" align="center" style="text-align:center" rowspan=""><?php echo $row2['cnt_name']; ?></td> <?php } ?>`

Comment: Edit your question to add the PHP code for the whole query -- it's much easier to read and not everyone bothers with the comments.

Comment: Have a look [at this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1170732/mysql-printing-data-just-once-for-each-grouping). The idea is to store the value in a variable on each loop iteration, and if the current loop's value differs from the variable, print a new one. The `$prev_group/$cur_group` in the answer are the storage variables, where you would store `$row2['cnt_name']`

Comment: Here's another example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13130858/printing-a-variable-only-when-it-changes